# Awk data match does not work regexp + date function

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying the following regular expression for matching dates, I'll use this regular expression in the bigger awk script, but this seems to not work some how.

```
echo "2343-23-23"| nawk '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,2}/'
```

The above line gives empty rows

Also, how do I convert the returned result converted to Date? I'd like to do a date compare on the matching results. I'd like to do something like the following ultimately

```
   echo "2016-01-01 11:12:13,234" | nawk '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,2}/ {if(date($0) > date("2016-01-01 10:00:00,234"){print "Yes";}}'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your regex but add `1` after it. Since `1` always evaluates to `true`, it performs default operation `{print $0}`.

```
awk '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,2}/1' <<< 1999-05-05
```

For older versions, you can try:

```
awk '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/1' <<< 1999-05-05
```

---

**Ideone Demo**

http://ideone.com/jyYUrM

Comment: Thank you that worked! any idea how to convert the string to date? see my last line in the question.

Comment: You may want to to pipe the result of awk to a bash script of this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84387/24179

Comment: what does that 1 do at the end?

Comment: Since `1` always evaluates to `true`, it performs default operation `{print $0}`

Answer (score 1):

nawk is a very old, non-POSIX awk which, among other things, doesn't support RE intervals. Get/use gawk if at all possible, otherwise some other modern awk, but if you're stuck with nawk then use `/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/`.

wrt your followup question - post a new question that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output and a much better description of your requirements for help with that as what you have currently written is unclear and could many one of several things.

Comment: not familiar with `nawk`, is there an `--re-interval` option to enable the interval expression?

Comment: @Kent no, that's just for old versions of gawk. nawk is just very old and so simply doesn't support RE intervals or character classes or other modern POSIX constructs.